# interactivity between slicer and map in power bi

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have a slicer and a map set to be interactive. The slicer behaves accordingly, but the other way is not. When a click a county in the map, my whole dashboard reflects the data accordingly. But when I choose a different county using the slicer, while the map selection is still active, I get no data because the initial county selected remains active. IS there a way to make interactivity between slicer and map? I mean map to slicer?

Answer (score 0):

i think your issue here is that both the slicer and map are set to filter whole page. you can either remove one of them and apply filter to each visual separately or apply a measure using CALCULATE(Measure,ALL(….